# can console.log content of signedCookie but can not access content

Tags: express, cookies, jwt

Have an express backend that sent signedCookies. the content of the signedCookie is a key and an object with 2 JWT as value

```
   "tokens":  "{ 
          "accessToken":"klkmlk", 
          "refreshToken":"kjlkjkle" 
      }"
```

When client is sending back the cookie, I can console log the "tokens", that shows the object, but for example `tokens.accessToken` returns `undefined`...
What's wrong ?

```
// parser with the secret jey to sign the cookie
app.use(cookieParser("secretKeyForCookie"));

// signed cookie options 
res.cookie("tokens", checkLogin.data, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        signed: true,
        maxAge: 100000,
        sameSite: true,
        path: "/",
      });



//, Object.keys lists keys but undefined when access one of the key
console.log(
      Object.keys(req.signedCookies.tokens), // returns ['accessToken', 'refreshToken']
      req.cookies.tokens["accessToken"] // undefined
    );
```

Comment: Did you try to use `req.signedCookies.tokens.accessToken`?

Comment: yes of course, same result. `Object.values(req.cookies.tokens)[0]` or `Object.values(req.cookies.tokens)[1]` provides the good result, but accessing via the key name failed. So weird

Comment: What does `req.cookies.tokens.accessToken` prints in the console?

Comment: `console.log(req.signedCookies.tokens.accessToken)` is working now... After a good night ;-). Will close the issue but it was weird